# Путь к изображению в другой директории при вызове через include

Tags: php, html

Приветствую, иметься директория, в ней:

```
 images/logo.png
 pages/photos.php
menu.php
footer.php
index.php
```

Файл **photos.php** содержит:

```
<?php include "../menu.php" ?>
<?php include "../footer.php" ?>
```

А в файле **menu.php**
Есть картинка

```
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

Когда открываю photos.php путь к картинки получается следующий pages/images/logo.png, как сделать чтобы путь к картинки шёл от места вызова?

Comment: как-то так: `include __DIR__ . '/logo.png';`

Answer (score 0):

Если директория является корнем сайта, то используйте такой адрес к картинке:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```